# DefaultHttpControllerSelector does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following constructor for my class which implements `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`:

```
public NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config) // error on this line
{
    _configuration = config;
    _duplicates = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    _controllers = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor>>(InitializeControllerDictionary);
}
```

VS gives me an error that reads, `DefaultHttpControllerSelector does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`.

But, when I go to the definition of `DefaultHttpControllerSelector` it shows this:

```
public DefaultHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration);
```

What am I doing wrong?  I am passing the correct parameter to the constructor, right?

**Note:** This is in MVC 5.

Comment: Where are you creating an instance of `NamespaceHttpControllerSelector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the base class constructor:

```
public NamespaceHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config)
    : base(config)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works well; but I am confused as to why this is necessary.   I am not familiar with this syntax.

Comment: If you leave out the explicit call to the `base(config)` constructor, then the default constructor `base()` will be called. In this case `base()` does not exist.